# DataOutputStream doesn't write entire integer on serialport

Tags: java, serial-port, outputstream

I'm looking for a solution for my problem with the Java DataOutputStream class.

I would like to send a 8-bit binary value to a micro controller which should be it's new address. So I tried to use the function DataOutputStream.writeByte(int arg0);

When I try to send the address `110` with the following code, I can see on the scope, that the serialport is sending 4 bytes ascii code `"1","1","0","LF"` but i would like to have `01101110` on the port. Do you see where I made the mistake?

```
SerialPort serialPort;
DataOutputStream outputStream;


    void sendeSerialPort(int adresse)
        {
            System.out.println("Sende: " + adresse);
            if (serialPortGeoeffnet != true)
                return;
            try {
                outputStream.writeByte(adresse);
                } 
            catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error when sending");
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Edit: This is what it looks like on the scope:

[110 sent as int with outputStream.writeByte(int)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm8tp.png)

Comment: A java `int` is 4 bytes (because it's a 32-bit signed quantity); if you want to send a byte you should be passing in a `byte`. Also, you should probably be using a `BinaryOutputStream`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Are you thinking of DataOutputStream to write binary?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What is a `BinaryOutputStream`?

Comment: @EJP I think I meant `OutputStream`; but I have use this [`BinaryOutputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/imaging/common/BinaryOutputStream.html) and maybe that's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `110` as a byte with `DataOutputStream.writeByte(110)` this produces just 1 byte which is the letter `n` in ASCII.

It only prints it as text and newline if you use `PrintStream.println(110)` or `PrintWriter.println(110)`